# SparkR bottleneck in createDataFrame?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I'm new to Spark, SparkR and generally all HDFS-related technologies. I've installed recently Spark 1.5.0 and run some simple code with SparkR:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/private/tmp/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths("/private/tmp/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib")
require('SparkR')
require('data.table')

sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)

n = 1000
x = data.table(id = 1:n, val = rnorm(n))

Sys.time()
xs <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, x)
Sys.time()
```

The code executes immediately. However when I change it to `n = 1000000` it takes about 4 minutes (time between two `Sys.time()` calls). When I check these jobs in console on port :4040, job for `n = 1000` has duration 0.2s, and job for `n = 1000000` 0.3s. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It took me a while due some unexpected problems on the way (hit some other bugs on the way not to mention I keep forgetting how weird things you can put  as a data frame column) but this should be resolved in 1.6.0: [SPARK-11086](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11086)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything particularly wrong. It is just an effect of a combination of different factors:

1. `createDataFrame` as it is currently (Spark 1.5.1) implemented is slow. It is a known issue described in [SPARK-8277](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8277).
2. Current implementation doesn't play well with `data.table`.
3. Base R is relatively slow. Smart people say it is a feature not a bug but it is still something to consider.

Until SPARK-8277 is resolved there is not much you can do but there two options you can try:

- use plain old `data.frame` instead of `data.table`. Using flights dataset (227496 rows, 14 columns):

  ```
  df <- read.csv("flights.csv")
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(createDataFrame(sqlContext, df), times=3)

  ## Unit: seconds
  ##                             expr      min       lq     mean   median
  ##  createDataFrame(sqlContext, df) 96.41565 97.19515 99.08441 97.97465
  ##        uq      max neval
  ##  100.4188 102.8629     3
  ```

  compared to `data.table`

  ```
  dt <- data.table::fread("flights.csv")
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(createDataFrame(sqlContext, dt), times=3)

  ## Unit: seconds        
  ##                             expr      min       lq     mean  median
  ##  createDataFrame(sqlContext, dt) 378.8534 379.4482 381.2061 380.043
  ##        uq     max neval
  ##  382.3825 384.722     3
  ```
- Write to disk and use `spark-csv` to load data directly to Spark DataFrame without direct interaction with R. As crazy as it sounds:

  ```
  dt <- data.table::fread("flights.csv")

  write_and_read <- function() {
      write.csv(dt, tempfile(), row.names=FALSE)
      read.df(sqlContext, "flights.csv",
          source = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
          header = "true",
          inferSchema = "true"
      )
  }

  ## Unit: seconds
  ##              expr      min       lq     mean   median
  ##  write_and_read() 2.924142 2.959085 2.983008 2.994027
  ##       uq      max neval
  ##  3.01244 3.030854     3
  ```

I am not really sure if really it makes sense to push data that can be handled in R to Spark in the first place but lets not dwell on that.

**Edit**:

This issue should be resolved by [SPARK-11086](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11086) in Spark 1.6.0.

Comment: I like your last comment! :)

Comment: Yeah... I could be biased here but I feel like SparkR takes most of the fun from R and gives very little in return. Scala API is powerful enough to be worth considering even on a relatively small data, especialy when  there is no idiomatic alternative beyond Breeze. In Python it is 50-50. But SparkR feels like a little bit clumsy database driver :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on your 2nd point as to why? A data.table is a data.frame and there are ways to access columns similar to a data.frame. Hence a bit puzzled. Also, on your 3rd point, relatively slow to what? And on what operation in this context?

Comment: @Arun Sure, but lets move it to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92330/room-for-zero323-and-arun).